# MongoDB/MongoID multikey special query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I have two collections: news and subscribes. Every news item has an array of strings - "tags". Every subscribe also has such "tags".

Subscribe's news items are items having all tags that subscribe has, and may be more. News item's subscribes are subscribes having any of this item's tags, but no any more.

When I want to get a Subscribe's news, I'm doing such request on Ruby MongoID:

```
NewsItem.where(:tags.all => @subscribe.tags)
```

How can I get all subscribes for some news item?

For example:

```
item.tags = ["foo", "bar"]

subscribe1.tags = ["foo"]
subscribe2.tags = ["bar"]
subscribe3.tags = ["foo", "bar"]
subscribe4.tags = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

item.subscribes should give subscribes 1..3, but subscribe4 should not be included, because it has a "baz" tag that is not included in item.tags

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what is expected here. Would you be able to provide: sample objects, expected query results. That will help us to craft the appropriate query.

Comment: I've edited example, so I hope you will understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you don't really want an `$all`. Instead, you are looking for some form `$subset` operator. There is [JIRA request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-974) for just such a thing, however it is not implemented at this time.

Comment: That's actually what I need. Sad, that it was not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the matching "on newsitem creation", so you do this operation on-demand and frequently. Turn the query around and do

```
Subscriber.all_in(tags: news_item.tags)
```

to find subscribers having all the tags of the newsitem. Is this how you wanted it?

In any case, with many subscribers, this will quickly get very intensive. You may use delayed job to handle it in the background. You should experiment with flattening arrays or setting other keys in order to index and speed up search.

Comment: no, that's not that I want. the way you showed (with all_in) it will give ["foo", "bar", "baz"] subscribe for news item ["foo", "bar"]. The reason I'm asking is that any of MongoDB standard operators (such as $in, $nin, $all etc) do not provide this functionality. Also, I use background job, but in this job to perform news items list caching I need to get subscribes lists for each news item.